# javascript array values singed as undefined

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, undefined

hello I want to get that database format :

```
 2013-10-10, 4, username1
 2013-10-10, 20, username2
 2013-10-12, 1, username1
```

to an array that looks like that :

```
 Array(
 [0] =>
 Array(
    [timestamp] => 2013-10-10,
    [username1] => 4, *from username1*
    [username2] => 20 *from username2*    
 [1] =>
 Array(
    [timestamp] => 2013-10-12,
    [username1] => 1
      )
```

)

ive tried :

```
function generatedata(data)
{
    var datas = [];
    for (item in data)
    {
       // console.log(data[item]['qty']); Logs well as numbers
        var dater = data[item]['timestamp'];
            if (!datas.hasOwnProperty(dater))
            {
                datas[dater] = [];
                var date = new Date(data[item]['timestamp'].replace(' ', 'T'));
                datas[dater]['date'] = date;
            }
        datas[dater][data[item]['name']] += data[item]['qty']; // gets assined as undefinedXX like undefined22 

    }
return datas;
}
```

the value assined by the name is 'undefined22' or 'undefined1' even if I check if the its undifend
i work with php and javascript
dont even have an idea

Comment: Why dont't you create proper array on server-side using php?

Comment: I need date values to be javascript date object

Comment: alsp I have to loop through the array with a condition every time.. and reloading it from php and sql everytime would be terrible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var timestamp_to_id = {};
var last_id = 0;

var out = [];

for(var i = 0, data; data = datas[i++];)
{
    var timestamp = new Date(data[0].replace(' ', 'T'));
    var qty = data[1];
    var username = data[2];

    var id = timestamp_to_id[timestamp];
    if (id === undefined) {
        id = timestamp_to_id[timestamp] = last_id ++;
        out[id] = { timestamp: timestamp };
    }

    out[id][username] = qty;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hWwtL/

See the console (F12)